# C# Looping over DataTable, compare with previous or next row

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, datatable

I am new to working with C# and databases.

I need to iterate over a Datatable (contained in a dataset) when I am iterating, I might need to compare the values from the current row with those from the previous row or next row.

I am currently iterating like this:

```
 foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Invoices"].Rows)
 {
     //Check if invoice id is equal to invoice id from previous/next row

 }
```

One way I can think of is to maintain "prev" variables to store the old value and compare and update as  go along but I wanted to see if the DataTable offered any built in options.

Thanks,
Calvin

Comment: Are you actually trying to find duplicates?

Comment: In a way, The source data is a little weird with multiple rows of data belonging to one object. I have sorted the data by the id's so I know when a new record begins. So I need to keep checking to see if the current id has changed or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for( int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Invoices"].Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    if( i > 0 )
    {
       // Compare with previous row using index
       if( ds.Tables["Invoices"].Rows[i]["Amount"] > ds.Tables["Invoices"].Rows[i - 1]["Amount"])
       {}
    }
    if( i < ds.Tables["Invoices"].Rows.Count - 1 )
    {
        if( ds.Tables["Invoices"].Rows[i]["Amount"] > ds.Tables["Invoices"].Rows[i + 1]["Amount"])
        {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I can build upon this and use it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you need random access, don't use `foreach`, but a plain-old-unhip `for` loop with an index.